# How to customize default LineStyleOrder to some plot functions?

Tags: matlab, fill, linestyle

I have just encountered an issue here, which I am unable to solve. As you may know, the `fill` function generates filled polygons using lines around the polygon and a colored polygon in inside. The problem is that in my `startup.m` file I have a line

```
set(0,'DefaultAxesLineStyleOrder','-|--|-.');
```

which is added to make it possible to have up to 21 unique lines in an ordinary plot (maybe a bit to optimistic, but more than 7 lines is definitely realistic). The problem is that this changes the LineStyleOrder for every plot. This will be annoying when I use `fill` since I will always have to call

```
fill(___,'LineStyle','-')
```

So what I wonder is, can I somehow customize the `'DefaultAxesLineStyleOrder'` for single functions? I would be able to investigate this by myself if `fill` would be written in MATLAB, but the function is a builtin function.

Does anyone know something about this?